# Listing specific values from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I've come across a JSON object at work from which I need to extract a list of email-adresses. It figures like this:

```
[
    {
        "key":"value",
        "key2":"value2",
        "key3":value3,
    },
    {
        "key":"value",
        "key2":"value2",
        "key3":value3,
    }
]
```

I want to write a JS script that extracts the value corresponding to key2. I can see it's possible through a for/in loop (https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_object_loop) but I can't figure out how to make it list **only** the value of key2 and not all of them. I know this is newbie question, but can someone help me accomplish this?

Comment: What should be the expected result in your case? Perhaps `obj.map(function(item) { return item.key2; })` is what you need.

Comment: @31piy that's exactly what I would do.

Comment: @TKoL -- I cannot be sure until the result's format is specified by the OP. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you do more research next time when you post another question.
This object loop, as you mentioned, will not work on your data as it as `array of objects` and not an object. So, will have to loop through as an array.
Here is what you can use:

```
    var obj = [
                 {
                   "key":"value",
                   "key2":"value2",
                   "key3":"value3",
                 },
                 {
                   "key":"value",
                   "key2":"value2",
                   "key3":"value3",
                 }
           ];
           var list = [];
           for(var i = 0; i<obj.length; i++) {
                list[i] = obj[i].key2;
           }
           console.log(list);
```

Your `list` will contain all the values you need.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Sorry, I couldn't find a specific reference to this. The for/in loop syntax is so confusing. :-(

Comment: @yolandayolanda not a problem :)   please tick (verify as correct) the answer if you found it useful and upvote it

Comment: Done. My upvote doesn't appear though cuz I'm a noob. :D Cheers

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
for (x in jsonObjectList) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x['key2'] + "<br>";
```

}